# pushover + curl --form-string: is badly used

Tags: curl, pushover

I'm trying to use [pushover](https://pushover.net/api/client) and getting the following error:

```sh
$ /usr/bin/curl -s \
  --form-string "token=mysecrettoken" \
  --form-string "user=mysecret user" \
  --form-string "hola!" \
  https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json

curl: option --form-string: is badly used here
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
curl --version                                       
curl 7.47.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you [read the manual](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html), the usage of the `--form-string` method is as follows:

```
--form-string <name=string>
```

Your error is generated on:

```
--form-string "hola!"
```

As it does not include the value for the key; simply adding an `=` causes this error to go away, as it turns it into a key/value pair.

```
--form-string "hola!="
```